# how to check whether the primary tab is already opened in salesforce service console?

Tags: service-cloud-console

In Service console, if the Primary tab is already open, we need to focus the primary tab. How to check whether the primary tab is already opened in console or not?

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest using a combination of getPrimaryTabIds and getPageInfo methods from the toolkit in order to determine if a tab is open, based on whatever criteria you want. A sample of what this code might look like for finding a tab with a given object ID is below

```
<apex:page>
<script src="/support/console/37.0/integration.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>

function findTab(criteria) {  

    sforce.console.getPrimaryTabIds(getPageInfo);

    function getPageInfo(result) { 
        if(result.ids.length==0) {
            alert('No Tabs Open'); 
            return; 
        }
        for(i=0; i<result.ids.length; i++) { 
            sforce.console.getPageInfo(result.ids[i], checkPresence);
        }
    }

    function checkPresence(result) { 
        if(JSON.parse(result.pageInfo).objectId==criteria) {
            alert('Tab Found');
        }
    }
}

</script>

<a href="#" onclick="findTab('001xx0000012345');">Find Tab</a>

</apex:page>
```

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_console.meta/api_console/sforce_api_console_getpageinfo.htm